# Should we count articles (a, an, the) during word count of the abstract of a research paper?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, abstract

In various peer-reviewed scientific journals, there is usually a word count limit for the abstract, e.g., 250 words in one such journal I am submitting my paper. I am confused whether I need to count all the words, including the *articles (a, an, the)* used with the nouns. Also, are there any other exceptions that need not be counted?

Comment: Do not be a concise person. Be concise.

Comment: Generally, you are expected to count all words. That includes articles. If that's not the case, the journal's instructions will make that obvious.

Comment: This question does not strongly depend on individual factors.

Answer (score 11):

Articles are words, so they count.

Answer (score 5):

You should assume you need to count all the words, short and long.  You can count an acronym or initialism as one word, but these are frowned upon in an abstract.  The only exception I can think of is if there are written instructions to the contrary.

Do not play tricks to limit the word count, for example, not putting an article before a noun.

Comment: Missed a chance for "Do not play tricks to limit word count, for example, not putting article before noun"

Comment: @Azor Ahai-him  Sadly, my attempt at such humor was edited away.

Comment: No jokes is the first rule of SE after all

Answer (score -3):

It depends on the individual journal you are writing to. There is no other possible answer.

Comment: Really? I've never heard of any system that let you leave out "stop words" when counting words for abstract/paper/whatever.

Comment: Neither do I, but what if OP is submitting an article to the Journal "articles are not words"?
We do not know.